# d3 stacked area tooltip

Tags: d3.js, charts, tooltip, stacked

I have this stacked area chart and I am trying to get the correct value, but have no real idea how. 
I was trying to place a transparent rectangle over the chart, but then realized that I still have no idea, how to get the values.

```
.on("mousemove", function(d) {
      tooltip
        .style("display", "inline-block")
        .html(d[0][1]);
    })
```

This will give me only a fix value.

Here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lO1Y2HDbWUTtpoo51uYZ?p=preview)

Maybe you guys have an idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the data object (d), though it is array-like, you can see it also has key and index properties, and that should lead you to the right data.

```
.on("mousemove", function(d) {
  tooltip
    .style("display", "inline-block")
    .html(d[d.index].data[d.key]);
})
```

The key is determined by the key accessor stack.keys(...) that you have defined in your plunker.

Also see the docs for the stack generator: https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#stacks